Colors in vercel build and in local build are not same, flutter
The colors appearing in the vercel flutter build web are not appearing the same as in local build. I am not using any explicit color settings, just seed color, except for the card shadowColor: Colors.transparent . Here is comparison
Local

Vercel build

